# Causes for elevated beta-HCG and AFP

Tags: endocrinology, male, tumors

I am interested in finding possible causes of elevated levels of beta-HCG and Alpha-1-Fetoprotein **in males**.

However, as much as I see, the only answer I find relates to cancer, and my curiosity is about the possible **exogenous** causes (for instance drugs), or in case there are none, other non-oncology related conditions that may cause these two levels to be out of range.

I have read that some pregnancy-related drugs can alter values, but in males how could this happen?

Comment: I don't know of any non-malignant causes.

Comment: Yes, that is understandable. So no drug, apart from beta-HCG itself or similars molecules, can increase the levels. I wonder if environmental causes can impact the levels of the two.